# Javascript - loader for table contents

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make a loader for only table contents?
I was thinking of something like this:

```
    <tbody id="loader">Loading...</tbody>
    <tbody id="table-content"></tbody>
```

Setting the #table-content to display none first:

```
#table-content {
  display: none;
}
```

And then when I am getting the data for the table showing the table content:

```
  table.style.display = 'block';
  loader.style.display = 'none';
```

But, that didn't work, loading would be there all the time.
I was also thinking of just having the Loading.. as text inside the table-content and then emptying it when I would start getting data:

```
table.innerHTML = '';
```

But, that didn't work either, I guess because all of that is invalid html, so I wonder how can I do that for a table content, have a gif that would be a loader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it the way you do because it's invalid HTML. This can be a different approach:

```js
function hideMe(el) {
  el.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.loading {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(70,70,70,.5);
  color: red;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="loading" onclick="hideMe(this)">Loading, click to hide</div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>col1</td>
      <td>col2</td>
      <td>col3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>col1</td>
      <td>col2</td>
      <td>col3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>col1</td>
      <td>col2</td>
      <td>col3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>col1</td>
      <td>col2</td>
      <td>col3</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I created a wrapper with a relative position, and set a loading div that cover the table. You can style it as you wish, and basically you need to only toggle it's `display` style to `block` when you need to load stuff, and set it to `none` when the loading is done.

Comment: How can I make it to take up some space where the table content should come, because now, when it is loading, the loader is where the ```thead```elements are, because there is nothing inside the table body?I have tried with setting the height but that didn't help

Comment: @Leff I added `min-height: 500px;` to the wrapper, will this help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position: absolute` on `#loader` element and then when you load data you can add new class that will hide loader with transition by setting opacity to 0

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  //After you load data
  document.querySelector('#loader').className += ' ' + 'hide'
}, 1000)
```

```css
table {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#loader {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: lightblue;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}
.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="loader"><tr><td>Loading...</td></tr></tbody>
  <tbody><tr><td>Content</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```